# importerror trying to convert pandas dataframe to R data frame

Tags: r, pandas, rpy2

I am attempting to convert some pandas dataframes to R objects for use in rpy2.

I am getting an error when i try to import the conversion the module. `from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri` yields `ImportError: cannot import name 're_type'` as follows:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/inference.py in <module>()
      6 from collections import Iterable
      7 from numbers import Number
----> 8 from pandas.compat import (PY2, string_types, text_type,
      9                            string_and_binary_types, re_type)
     10 from pandas._libs import lib

ImportError: cannot import name 're_type'
```

I haven't really seen any discussion of this error elsewhere.

in terms of dependencies, i am using `pandas 0.23.4`, `rpy2 2.9.4`, `R 3.4`, and it is running on the docker jupyter container `datascience-notebook`

Really hoping someone could help me here!